# SOLID principles, Repository pattern and EntityFramework cache in Asp Net Mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, solid-principles

I have a visual studio solution using solid pattern. I have a IRepository (Crud implementation), IDbFactory (used by a repository), IUnitOfWork. I also have services, who uses repositories to build custom querys and complex database operation. I am using also IoC pattern with Ninject.
In a web mvc controller I use only services to access to database. 
A repository receive a IDbFactory who build a EntityFramework Context.
I have some problems:

- In a service when i have to access to two tables for join them i should use two repositories, calling the GetAll() method of both of them. In this case both repositories should share the same EntityFramework Context.
- The previous case indicates me that the DbContext should be shared by All repositories, so I can join IQueryables in a service from different repositories.
- To a accomplish this goal I configured in the IoC container, the DbContext in singleton scope. So every repository shares the same DbContext.
- The problem with this solution is that the DbContext have a cache. So, when a external process (different to the web project) changes my data the DbContext do not realize it, and the Web project do not shows real data sometimes.
- I read about destroy the DbContext in every repository call, but i cant do this because every repository should use the same DbContext

I there something wrong with my Project structure? This is something i must fix in the repository layer? What shoul I do? The project is in developing stage, so I can change the data access architecture. I like use IQueryables in the controller so users filters in data grids produce sql querys.

Comment: CodeReview offers a better forum for these types of questions. For example: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/ef-code-first-with-repository-unitofwork-and-dbcontextfactory

Comment: This is a classic example of why building an IRepository is usually a waste of time. EF already implements repository and unit of work and abstracts the db, so now you have dropped another layer of abstraction on top to achieve what? Wait until you start saving things in one repository and it saves changes in another because the objects are attached to the same context. If you are in something like a website or service you can make the DbContext lifespan per request, but IRepository is usually more trouble than its worth,

Comment: another problem is that your DbContext is a singleton.  That means every user is running the same DbContext.  breaks the inherent unit of work in a DBContext.  you want a dbcontext created for each unit of work.

Comment: relevent code review link http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47879/unit-of-work-and-repository-with-entity-framework-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in terms of your stated issue here, there's nothing wrong with your project structure. The problem derives from using a Singleton scope. You should be using Request scope, instead, for a web application. This ensures that you get a new context with each request, so there will not be overlap between different requests and even different clients, which can be extremely dangerous.

That said, your project structure is over-engineered. The repository/unit of work patterns are intended for low-level data access. An ORM, like Entity Framework, handles all that, and in fact, Entity Framework already implements these patterns. The `DbContext` is the unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository. Adding your own repository/unit of work layer on top of this is redundant and unnecessary. Your services should utilize your Entity Framework context directly. Even then, having a plurality of services is probably unnecessary as well, depending on what they do. If they all work with the same data source (i.e. an Entity Framework context) and particularly if they all work with the *same* Entity Framework context, then they should really all be rolled into one.

In my own personal projects, I utilize a single "service" class with generic methods per unique context instance. The generic methods let me work with any entity belonging to that context without having to new up additional instances of the "service" class. By ensuring that everything implements one or more interfaces and using dependency injection to satisfy interface constraints, the underlying data layer is completely factored out. I have a [series of posts](http://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/) that goes into greater detail if you're interested.

I say all this because it seems you're overly focused on patterns and "best practices". Those are just *guides*. They're like training wheels on a bicycle. They're all based on various principles of good code design. Learn and apply the *principles* and don't worry about checking all the boxes on some sort of list of design patterns.

As an interesting aside, Stack Overflow's core codebase actually eschews a number of patterns (even dependency injection) because they're laser-focused on raw performance, and some design patterns, when applied, actually hinder performance. The point is that how an application is designed should be based on the needs of the particular application. Design patterns should only be applied in as much as they are congruent with the needs of your application, not just because you think you're supposed to.

Comment: One reason to layer a UnitOfWork/Repository pattern over the Entity Framework is to abstract away the entity framework from the other code. This helped me in a few instances. 

Like when I wanted to upgrade the entity framework and there were some changes that broke the unit of work repository, I was able to make the changes once and not have issues with the rest of the code. 

I also added some entities into DocumentDb and was able to make a repository mimick what the existing repositories were doing and the rest of the code looks basically the same when retriieving these items.

Comment: Nope. There's other ways to achieve the same result and repository/unit of work is the worst way. As I described in my answer, I have a single reusable class that can work with *anything* and Entity Framework is completely invisible.

Comment: Please explain how it is 'the worst way'? It has worked successfully for me for a number of years with no complaints? There is no possible way that is worse then using a unit of work? There is no way you could possibly dream of that would be worse?

Comment: If you have a generic repository whose only purpose is to take the CRUD out of the rest of the application and eliminate repetitive code (DRY), this is a reasonable approach. However, if you have specialized repositories that tend to be a "kitchen sink" of operations just because they pertain to a specific entity, it is violating the SRP. If you are open to changing the architecture, you could work around this by using a [CQS pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) for those "oddball" queries/updates, and keep a set of generic repositories in place for CRUD.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Could you please share the reusable class that can work with anything? I am interested becuause I am also using custom repositories to have a layer only for my queris.

Comment: @MikeS: It's a maintenance nightmare. It's one thing when you're abstracting raw SQL, since that's even worse to maintain, but for abstracting an ORM, especially an ORM that *already* implements these patterns, it's redundant and useless. The Repo/UoW are not and never were intended to abstract an ORM, applying these patterns to that end is a bastardization of the pattern.

Comment: @jannagy02: See the link in my answer.

Comment: @ChrisPratt None of the nightmare you are describing has been my experience but I'll accept that that has been yours. I just tend to respect more the opinions of those who don't speak in absolutes like 'it's the worst way'. You are right the Entity Framework implements these patterns but only with data stores that it can support. When I added in some DocumentDb, I was grateful to have abstracted away the Entity Framework so I could use another mechanism for data persistence without affecting the way the rest of the code interacted with the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the lifecycle of the DbContext should last for the entire business unit, in MVC applications this is per HttpRequest. It provides a transaction from the start of sending a request to receive a response by user.

Second, you shouldn't have the `GetAll()` function in the base repository. This is very wrong solution, which can influences on performance of your application. You should create the function like: `GetByQuery(Func<T, bool> whereQuery, int skip, int take)` where T is the generic type of your entity class. Alternatively, you can add a parameter for sorting.

Maybe you should think about resignation of the Repository Pattern? How big is your project? Is it possibility to change the data storage in the future? If not, you can operate directly on DbContext in your services. Entity Framework is a kind of implementation of the repository pattern and UnitOfWork.

Comment: if his GetAll() return an IQueryable, then he can add predicates, skip take, sorting without a performance penalty because EF uses deferred execution

Comment: I think the performance penalty he's talking about is loading all the records of a table. If there's millions of records, this could be very costly. However, it's all in how it's used. Even only allowing public access to something like `GetByQuery` could still be used to get *all* records, if you simply apply no limits. Having a `GetAll` method is not a problem in itself; it just must be used responsibly.

Comment: right. which is why i mentioned IQueryable. He doesn't mention the return type of GetByQuery which could be an IQueryable and not an List<T>.